# Delayed job not processing in the Background (Rails - 4.0.1 and delayed_job_active_record - 4.0.1) on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Using Rails(4.0.1) and delayed_job_active_record(4.0.1) for background tasks in my application. DJ works fine only when I use rake jobs:work in production mode. But I want it has to run daemon process, also this process no more alive after sometime.

If I run the bin/delayed_job start RAILS_ENV=production.  I can able to the pid file in tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid. The process is in alive. But nothing is working. Any clue on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be delayed_jobs are failing due to some reason/error. Try installing dj_mon (https://github.com/akshayrawat/dj_mon) in rails application and view jobs log.

If delayed jobs services is shutting down due to memory leakage or some unknown reason, you may try to install and configure 'monit' scripts on your server. It will restart delayed jobs service automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I am using https://github.com/mojombo/god to monitor the DJ activities. But I want to know is this the issue from the DJ or Rails or any memory issues..

Comment: I think it is memory issue. In our system, delayed jobs crashed when server memory goes beyond 90%. It is also a good idea to monitor nginx/puma/passenger or whatever server you are using so that if some process is using extensive memory, monit / god restart that process. In our case, it was passenger that was main source of memory leakage.